# Calculate average date difference between records in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, datetime, average

I have a list on when items have been handed out. The table has the following structure:

- primary key - autonumber itemname
- itemid - number
- datehandedout - date/time

I want to calculate the average length of time between when one object is given out and the next one is given out. There will be a number of different items for which the average time between handouts needs to be listed for.

So something like (pseudocode):

average( [thisrecord]![datehandedout] - [lastrecord]![datehandedout] )

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a *very* slow query:

```
SELECT Avg(DateDiff("h",[datehandedout],(
    SELECT TOP 1 datehandedout 
    FROM tbl tx 
    WHERE tx.datehandedout > t.datehandedout))) AS Difference
FROM tbl AS t
```

Add another Where statement to limit the number of records returned when you test, for example:

```
WHERE Year([datehandedout])=2010
```